# java detection of html document nodes

Tags: java, html, events, text

Suppose I have a text in Java from a html document. It is possible to detect mouse events related to document nodes?
It is possible to get the id of the node of that document from the event?
I did it before using JavaScript.

Comment: more details please, you want to get onOver effects or something else?

Comment: what do you mean by event. If the html document is rendered in a browser, only javascript can be used to detect events and react.